# Is it posible to Limit salesforce Outbound IP

Tags: integration

We all know the situation, Salesforce outbound requests come from a variety of IP addresses:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1

Currently we are trying to integrate with another API and their firewall must whitelist IPs. The caveat is that the firewall ranges are limited to blocks of 64 addresses and they refuse to add all of the IPs listed for the region in the document above.

So, has anyone had success with some voodoo magic, a contact at SF, or something that can be done to reduce the range of IPs for a specific org?

I have a feeling that we will just have to not integrate with the vendor but it is a high priority for our client sso I though I would check if anyone had magic keywords to say when speaking with SF support or if it is simply just not possible.

I suspect the latter

Comment: They really won't whitelist the whole region? That seems unreasonable.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Nope. They have denied the request from other sf customers before. The was their initial response so we are till trying but I wanted to cover other bases as well.

Comment: On a side note anyone know how to unstick a key on a mac..my s key is posesed.....lol

Comment: @Eric [This youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XT2E4YSB9I) shows you how to properly remove, clean, and replace the sticky key. Remember, doing this likely voids any warranty you may have left...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every pod has just a handful of IP addresses assigned to them. For example, if you were on na1, you could expect the IP address to normally be 96.43.146.204 or 96.43.146.80 (as of the time of this answer). You can do a simple dns lookup (e.g. nslookup in Windows) to confirm the current IP addresses. The danger, of course, is that if salesforce later changes the IP addresses, for whatever reason, your integrations will stop working unexpectedly. The pod IP addresses tend to be stable for months or even years at a time, but if you don't whitelist all recommended IP addresses, you risk unexpected failures.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes it much more difficult to install our package and get it connected to the vendor for the client not to mention much less reliable. In the end the vendor would end up whitelisting all addresses anyways as customers are onboarded....But it is a possible solution like I asked for +1....

Comment: @Eric They're not using all of the IP addresses anyways, there's a lot of room for future expansion, but yes, they'll eventually end up doing most of the IPs at some point. Depending on what resources you have available, you could set up an API proxy (a proxy that allows connections from any Salesforce IP) then have them whitelist just the one IP address. That, of course, will incur some tech expense for your organization, though.