# How to get my org's IP address? and I want to make sure that each organization has only a unique IP?

Tags: org, organization-wide

My org has some callouts to another server. but the server requires to add IP address to whitelist. So I need to know how many IP addresses does each org have and how can I get it through coding or something else.

Comment: [Is it posible to Limit salesforce Outbound IP](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176295/2995)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce's IP ranges can be found on this page - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000003652&type=1.  Your particular org can possibly attempt external connections from any IP address in that range, although as the [answer linked in comments](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/176295/2995) notes, you can use nslookup to find the IP range of your particular pod, at the risk of that range being subject to change without notice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we get IP address by apex code?

Answer (score 2):

How to check your SF IP address:
Add remote site setting - This endpoint https://salesforcelwc.herokuapp.com
Use this script to access to that endpoint:

```
HTTP h = new HTTP();
HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
req.setEndPoint('https://salesforcelwc.herokuapp.com/myip');
req.setMethod('GET');
HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

In the debug log you'll see the IP in this format:
[image]

Comment: Salesforce orgs do not have single, static IP addresses. This may give you _one_ IP that the org's pod is _currently_ using, but that is subject to change at any time including on the next request.

Comment: As we occasionally get requests for specific IPs, I had used this solution before.  I tried to run it today and am getting a response that the app doesn't exist anymore.  Just as a general FYI.